# Python parou de funcionar

Tags: python, python-3.x

Não estou sabendo muito bem identificar o erro, então vou explicar o problema.

Contextualizando:

Estava eu, programando em Python, mais precisamente em Django, até que quis começar a dar um hello world na web 3.0 (começou aqui) onde o mesmo so funcionaria se eu atualiza-se o meu Microsoft Visual Studio, fiz o que me solicitou e finalmente consegui fazer o tal do hello world... Porém, no outro dia, não tive acesso mais a nenhuma função do python. (aqui de fato começou o pesadelo)

Pra mostrar a vocês, peguei um blog que fiz pra fazer essa analise com os senhores(as)...

Eu consigo entrar no meu ambiente virtual, normalmente e acessar a pasta onde está o manage.py ... (Mas não consigo criar)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem, notei que as bibliotecas que antes estavam instalados, aparecem no VScode que falta fazer a importação...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... Fui la e tentei instalar, mas aparece esse erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... Ok, relevei o detalhe, e tento dar o comando py manage.py runserver (sempre funcionou normalmente) ... Porém o resultado e esse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo nem criar uma venv, que da o msm erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... Ele chega a criar a pasta, mas não cria o arquivo .bat pra ativar o mesmo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu ja desinstalei e re-instalei diversas e diversas vezes
Tirei TODOS os arquivos Python do sistema windows e fiz as instalações normalmente
Porém toda vez da o mesmo erro.
Instalei a versão 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 ... até o 3.10 que até o presente dia é o que esta disponível como versão estável do Python, e nada, por fim, me mantive na versão 3.9 (sem critério).

Mesmo mudando o interpretador do VScode, não funciona, o erro se mantem o mesmo, tentei utilizar todos que estavam disponiveis

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procuro na internet em diversos sites, inclusive aqui e não tive sucesso.

Faz um tempo que estou com esse problema no meu notbook, quero evitar ao máximo formatar o memso, pois tenho muitos arquivos grandes e não tenho como upar no drive e nem em pendrive (Projetos de Unreal, Revit, 3dmax ...), fora muitos outros softwares ja instalados e configurados que uso no meu dia a dia.

Se alguem conseguir me ajudar, serei eternamente grato

Comment: Bom, consegui criar uma venv completa pelo PyCharm, posso crirar uma env por la, porém todos os outros erros se mantiveram. ou seja, so terei a venv, nao consigo instalar nada nele, pq da erro, ate msm pelo settings e não nem consigo rodar o codigo pra ver se funcionou, da o mesmo erro postado acima....

Answer (score -1):

Verifique se as variáveis de ambiente do S.O. e os caminhos da IDE estão configurados corretamente para a nova versão, pois acredito que como você não consegue criar um `venv` ou instalar uma lib/modulo parece que o python não está "se localizando".

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Fiz esse procedimento e ainda continuou dando o mesmo erro. Mas obrigado pela sugestão de solução

Comment: você reiniciou o computador/IDE após alterar as variáveis de ambiente? no windows se não me engano é necessário reiniciar a máquina, no Linux basta realizar um `$ source ${arquivo_alterado}`